# SVG Image Blurring/Flashing issue with Google Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-svg

I'm stuck with blurring issue for secondary SVG image inside primary SVG response on every Ajax call in Google Chrome browser.

Only:

- On ajax call, I'm getting SVG content as Ajax response.
- Inside that response, I have primary SVG image that contains SVG image tag with:

  ```
  xlink:href(source) presenting secondary svg image file.
  ```
- I'm trying to append that SVG response to HTML division tag, but this secondary SVG image is displayed blurred with Google Chrome Browser only.

I referred this link: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119693 and Googling over this topic, but search result ends up only with Google Chrome cache issue with SVG content.

I tried removing this cache issue by appending a random string as a parameter behind secondary SVG image source path/location. Now it gives a fresh response without blurring secondary SVG image, but it introduces issue of flashing/blinking of secondary SVG image on each Ajax call.

Please suggest the possible ways to get rid of this flashing issue in Chrome browser.

Regards,
Vishal